# Not getting the correct count in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am totally new to `SQL`. I have a simple select query similar to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(col1) FROM table1
```

There are some 120 records in the table and shown on the `GUI`.
For some reason, this query always returns a number which is less than the actual count.

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might have some null values in col1 column. Aggregate functions ignore nulls.
try this

```
SELECT COUNT(ISNULL(col1,0)) FROM   table1
```

Answer (score 17):

Try

```
select count(*) from table1
```

**Edit:** To explain further, `count(*)` gives you the rowcount for a table, including duplicates and nulls. `count(isnull(col1,0))` will do the same thing, but *slightly* slower, since `isnull` must be evaluated for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly tangential, but there's also the useful

```
SELECT count(distinct cola) from table1
```

which gives you number of distinct column in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the correct count

As per https://learn.microsoft.com

COUNT(*) returns the number of items in a group. This includes NULL values and duplicates.

COUNT(ALL expression) evaluates an expression for each row in a group and returns the number of nonnull values.

COUNT(DISTINCT expression) evaluates an expression for each row in a group and returns the number of **unique, non null** values.

In your case you have passed the column name in COUNT that's why you will get **count of not null records**, now you're in your table data you may have null values in given column(col1)

Hope this helps!