# What does "select count(1) from table_name" on any database tables mean?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

When we execute `select count(*) from table_name` it returns the number of rows.

What does `count(1)` do? What does `1` signify here? Is this the same as `count(*)` (as it gives the same result on execution)?

Comment: Interesting question.  I'd also be interested in whether the answer is implementation-dependent (e.g. whether the result of the query is the same in SQL Server as it is in Oracle).

Answer (score 140, accepted):

The parameter to the COUNT function is an expression that is to be evaluated for each row. The COUNT function returns the number of rows for which the expression evaluates to a non-null value. ( * is a special expression that is not evaluated, it simply returns the number of rows.)

There are two additional modifiers for the expression: ALL and DISTINCT. These determine whether duplicates are discarded. Since ALL is the default, your example is the same as count(ALL 1), which means that duplicates are retained.

Since the expression "1" evaluates to non-null for every row, and since you are not removing duplicates, COUNT(1) should always return the same number as COUNT(*).

Comment: Remember select DISTINCT coloumn1 from table1  != select count(DISTINCT coloumn1) from table1;

Comment: Also count(1) here 1 is not coloumn no, it is a expression. e.g) select 1 from table1; will print 1 no of times for no of rows that table has.

Comment: select count(DISTINCT/ALL columnName) from table1; will return no of all/distinct NOT NULL values of the column (columnName).

Comment: select DISTINCT column1 from table1; will include one NULL value in the column (column1). select count(DISTINCT coloumn1) from table1; will not include even one NULL row.

Comment: +1 for clarifying this `COUNT(1)` confusing syntax. Now... if *"COUNT(1) should always return the same number as COUNT(*)"*, why have two syntax forms, different only by a single character, that do exactly the same?

Comment: @datps - There are actually an unlimited number of expressions that give the same result. COUNT('Hello, world!') should work just as well. (I haven't tried it.) So the question is, why create a special expression (*) when there are already an unlimited number of ways of doing the same thing? I can't speak for the creators of SQL (who have many sins to atone for :) ), but it was probably so people wouldn't have to arbitrarily choose a non-null expression. That would have muddied the intent of the author of the query. "Why did they write 1 instead of 2? This must mean something!"

Comment: Thanks! So the question now should be "why do SQL programmers use syntax other than COUNT(*) ?"   (rhetoric :-))

Comment: @datps You can't use DISTINCT with `COUNT(*)`. But you can use `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 1)...WHERE id=...` which gives `0` or `1` (depending upon whether or not a record exists) which is easier to convert to a boolean than `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 30):

Here is [a link](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:40208915257337) that will help answer your questions. In short:

> count(*) is the correct way to write
>   it and count(1) is OPTIMIZED TO BE
>   count(*)  internally -- since
>
> a) count the rows where 1 is not null
>   is less efficient than
>   b) count the rows

Answer (score 24):

Difference between count(*) and count(1) in oracle?

count(*) means it will count all records i.e each and every cell
BUT

count(1) means it will add one pseudo column with value 1 and returns count of all records

Answer (score 9):

This is similar to the difference between

```
SELECT * FROM table_name and SELECT 1 FROM table_name.
```

If you do

```
SELECT 1 FROM table_name
```

it will give you the number 1 for each row in the table.  So yes `count(*)` and `count(1)` will provide the same results as will `count(8)` or `count(column_name)`

Comment: count(column_name) is not quite the same - it doesn't count rows with  null in that column. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169784

Comment: Hmm, actually that's for SQL Server. Oracle may work differently I suppose.

Comment: Count should never use NULL values as per standard SQL, ORacle and SQL Server should have the same behaviour in this regard.

Comment: "similar to the difference between SELECT * FROM table_name and SELECT 1 FROM table_name." -- not really. SELECT * and SELECT 1 are different. SELECT (*) and SELECT (1) give the same result.

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference.

`COUNT(1)` is basically just counting a constant value 1 column for each row.  As other users here have said, it's the same as `COUNT(0)` or `COUNT(42)`.  Any non-`NULL` value will suffice.

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:2603224624843292::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156151916789

The Oracle optimizer did apparently use to have bugs in it, which caused the count to be affected by which column you picked and whether it was in an index, so the COUNT(1) convention came into being.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) from <table name>
```

should do the exact same thing as

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  from <table name>
```

There may have been or still be some reasons why it would perform better than `SELECT COUNT(*)`on some database, but I would consider that a bug in the DB.

```
SELECT COUNT(col_name) from <table name>
```

however has a different meaning, as it counts only the rows with a non-null value for the given column.

Answer (score 3):

in oracle i believe these have exactly the same meaning

Comment: Does the 1 refer to column one?

Comment: no, 1 refers to the constant number 1. When you say, ORDER BY 1, it refers to column one.

Comment: that's what I wondered a while back, but you can specify any number which is greater than the column count, still the result is same. So its definitely not column number.

Comment: @dacracot: it may but i don't believe so. From what i understand oracle just re-writes count(1) to be count(*) in the background

Answer (score 2):

You can test like this:

```
create table test1(
 id number,
 name varchar2(20)
);

insert into test1 values (1,'abc');
insert into test1 values (1,'abc');

select * from test1;
select count(*) from test1;
select count(1) from test1;
select count(ALL 1) from test1;
select count(DISTINCT 1) from test1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on who you ask, some people report that executing `select count(1) from random_table;` runs faster than `select count(*) from random_table`. Others claim they are exactly the same.

This [link](http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2008/08/what-is-faster-select-count-or-select-countpk.html) claims that the speed difference between the 2 is due to a FULL TABLE SCAN vs FAST FULL SCAN.

Comment: You're misinterpreting the link. LS is making the point that COUNT(COLUMN) can be the same as and faster than COUNT(*), but only when no NOT NULL columns are indexed but COLUMN is indexed and actually has no null values. More of a trick question.

Comment: I was trying to use the link to document the claim that, in some circumstances, COUNT(1) could be faster than COUNT(*).

Some earlier answers had made the statement that there were no differences between the 2, and I was providing a possible counter example.