# How to LIMIT a Query which is already been selected?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to LIMIT a Query which is already been selected. I know I can directly do it in my query select, but due to some logics of the code, if I do that way I have to run the query selection twice which (I believe) will increase the computational time!
So, what I am trying is this:

```
$query1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tableName  WHERE someconditions");
```

then, I need to re-select a sub-selection of the $query1 for my Pagination. What I am trying to do is something like this;

```
$query2 = LIMIT($query1, $limit_bigin, $limit_end);
```

where `$limit_bigin`, `$limit_end` provide the LIMITING range (start and end respectively).

Could someone please let me know how I could do this?

P.S. I know I can do it directly by:

```
$query1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tableName  WHERE someconditions");
$query2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE someConditions LIMIT $limit_bigin, $limit_end");
```

But this is running the query twice and slows down the process (I must run the first query without limits due to some logics of the program)

**EDIT 1**
As per the answers I tried using *array_slice in PHP*. BUT, since Query is an object it doesn't give the results that was expected. A NULL is resulted form

```
array_slice($query1, $start, $length, FALSE)
```

Comment: If you definitely have to run the unlimited query first, why not perform the limiting in PHP?

Comment: if you already have the whole query fetched from your database why would you need to get it again with some kind of pagination? Just paginate it with your PHP code.

Comment: **SQL is orderless by definition**.. Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is meaningless and won't guarantee the same results even when running the same query twice. .

Comment: If you fetch all the rows from `$query1`, you can just use `array_slice()` to extract the rows your interested in.  Otherwise you may be able to use `mysqli_stmt_data_seek()` to position the query and read the amount of rows your after.

Comment: How may I limit it using PHP ? thanks

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) why do you need to perform the full query in the first place? If you intend to paginate what's the purpose of selecting everything? If it's just to know the total number of results can't you `SELECT COUNT(1)...` instead?

Comment: @BuV8 oooooooh; you really need to pick up some more MySQL / PHP coding tips. [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42576068/3536236). And see also [why this is so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181272/what-does-select-count1-from-table-name-on-any-database-tables-mean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already carried out the query and the result set has been returned to your PHP, you can not *then* `LIMIT` it. As you state, then running a second SQL execution of a subpart of the same query is wasteful and repetative.

**D**on't 
**R**epeat 
**Y**ourself.

[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

As I said above, repetition causes issues with maintainability as you can easily forget about repetition, tweaking one SQL and forgetting to tweak the other.

**D**on't 
**R**epeat 
**Y**ourself.

[DRY](https://metova.com/dry-programming-practices/).

## Use PHP instead

Once you have executed the query, the result set is then passed back to PHP.

So assuming you have a `$var` with the contents of you SQL query, then you simply need to select the valid rows from the `$var`, not from the database [again].

You can do this using PHP numerous Array functions. Particularly [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

So;

```
$query1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tableName  WHERE someconditions");
```

Now, to select the second page, say for example rows 10 to 20:

```
$query2 = array_slice($query1, (10-1), 10 );
```

This wil then "slice" the part of the array you want. Remember that the array counts will start at zero so to grab row 10 (of an index starting at 1, Typical of a MySQL Auto Increment Primary Key), then you will need to select X number of rows *from* row (10-1) .

Please also read the manual for PHP [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

## Further

As referenced in comments, there is no guarentee that your SQL will return the same values each time *in the same order*, so it is highly recommended to order your results:

```
$query1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tableName 
          WHERE someconditions ORDER BY primary_key_column");
```

## Example Data:

```
$query1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tableName  WHERE someconditions ORDER BY id");
/***
  $query1 = array {
          0 => array { 'id' => 1, 'user' => "Jim", 'colour' => "Blue" },
          1 => array { 'id' => 2, 'user' => "Bob", 'colour' => "Green" },
          2 => array { 'id' => 3, 'user' => "Tom", 'colour' => "Orange" },
          3 => array { 'id' => 4, 'user' => "Tim", 'colour' => "Yellow" },
          4 => array { 'id' => 5, 'user' => "Lee", 'colour' => "Red" },
          5 => array { 'id' => 6, 'user' => "Amy", 'colour' => "Black" }
   }  
***/

$page = 2;
$size = 3; // number per page.
$start = ($page - 1) * $size; //page number x number per page.

// Select the second page of 3 results.    
$query2 = array_slice($query1, $start, $size , FALSE);

/***
  $query2 = array {
          0 => array { 'id' => 4, 'user' => "Tim", 'colour' => "Yellow" },
          1 => array { 'id' => 5, 'user' => "Lee", 'colour' => "Red" },
          2 => array { 'id' => 6, 'user' => "Amy", 'colour' => "Black" }
   }  
***/
```

You can then use these in a `foreach` or other standard array manipulation technique.

Comment: For the ordering I order it by the Time when the perticular row is created in the DB Table. Is is suffice?

Comment: @BuV8 As long as it's ordered by something, so that repeated queries will always return the same values, in the same order.

Comment: array_slice gives a warning saying: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given (and shows the line where I do the slicing using PHP), AND nothing is Output (a NULL is given).....what might be wrong?

Comment: Please refer my EDIT 1

Comment: @BuV8 The *result set* from your Query will be an array of data, this array *may be held within an object*, but you simply need to save it as an array `$var`, even if it's within the object, such as `$queryResult->resultArray` and then use this in your `array_slice()`

Comment: @BuV8 To further clarify ; `$object->arrayVarOfResultSet` and then use this in your `array_slice()` operations.

Comment: So, just to make sure I use: $var = $queryResult->resultArray($query) to save it as an array?

Comment: @BuV8 Basically, probably. This is a very basic question. You should be comfortable with `$var` types and using $vars correctly (using objects as objects and arrays as arrays). Read the manual and see also [`gettype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php)

Comment: Could someone please explain how I could convert $query to an array? I tried to do it as Martin was explaining but still no luck.... what I tried was: $var = $query->resultArray($quey), but it's not working and I am not familiar with object to array conversions. A help is much appreciated....

Comment: @BuV8 please *edit* your question with a *new* part at the bottom, showing the shape of your `$query` references. Cheers.