# How to count unique occurences of column in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Given a table such as:

```
| ID | Value  |
|-------------|
| 1  | "some" |
| 1  | "some" |
| 1  | "value"|
| 2  | "some" |
| 3  | "some" |
| 3  | "value |
| 3  | "value |
```

How can I count the number of unique occurrences of value for each ID?

So you end up with a table such as:

```
| ID | Value  | number |
|-------------|--------|
| 1  | "some" |   2    |
|    | "value"|   1    |
| 2  | "some" |   1    |
| 3  | "some" |   1    |
|    | "value |   2    |
```

I attempted to use `OVER(PARTITION BY ID order by Value)` to separate the table by IDs and count the separate values. However this counts the number of unique occurences, but then adds them together. So I end up with a table such as:

```
| ID | Value  | number |
|-------------|--------|
| 1  | "some" |   2    |
| 1  | "some" |   2    |
| 1  | "value"|   3    |
| 2  | "some" |   1    |
| 3  | "some" |   1    |
| 3  | "value |   3    |
| 3  | "value |   3    |
```

Is there a way to count the unique values like the second example I gave?

Comment: I don't understand your desired results.  Why is `id` missing from some rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, value, COUNT(1) number
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY id, value
```

with result

```
Row id  value   number   
1   1   some    2    
2   1   value   1    
3   2   some    1    
4   3   value   2    
5   3   some    1
```

Comment: It works! Can you explain how COUNT(1) does that? Assuming '1' is the index of the column?

Comment: @JoeBoggs See this question for a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181272/what-does-select-count1-from-table-name-on-any-database-tables-mean

Comment: @JoeBoggs - `COUNT(1)` here is equivalent to `COUNT(*)` and just counts number of rows in the group without taking into account actual values of any columns. If you would use `COUNT(col)` that would count ONLY rows where `col` is not NULL!  You can test this running following query - `SELECT COUNT(1), COUNT(*), COUNT(col) FROM (SELECT 1 col UNION ALL SELECT NULL)` - note - this is query for #standardSQL. The reason I am usually using `COUNT(1)` vs `COUNT(*)` is just historical as I came from db's stone ages when performance of those were quite different - which is not a case nowadays